# Besides the Season 5 premire, have there been any other post credit scenes in The Walking Dead?

Tags: credits, the-walking-dead

I personally never watch after the credits, but my friend told me to watch till the end to see the post credit scenes, and I wondered, if there had been any other scenes I had missed by turning off when the credits started.

Does anybody know of any?

Comment: Good question, I always turned off the credits to avoid spoilers and missed this too.

Comment: I wondered how many of the TV shows I've watched have had this but I missed it, because I never watch credits, but I think that list is far too big for a question here!

Comment: @TomHart: The Wikipedia article [Post-credits scene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-credits_scene) gives some examples and links (under "External links") to two websites that collect movies that have such scenes, but I don’t know how good these sites are. In the IMDb, such things are typically listed under the "Crazy Credits" section, but you’d have to check this step-by-step for every movie/episode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to the IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3297776/crazycredits), it is the only episode so far:

> Unlike in any previous episode, there is a 'stinger' scene, ie. *after* the end credits are completely over.

---

**Update**:

After this epsiode, there was another season 5 episode with a stinger scene: S05E08

[From the IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3714498/crazycredits):

> Just like in the season premiere, there is a 'stinger' scene (actually several scenes), ie. *after* the end credits are completely over.

> Together, the stingers complete each other, being the only segments in the first half of season 5 to feature a character that has been absent for a long time.

> This is the second Walking Dead episode to contain an after credits scene, and, as of Episode 4x08, the longest.